# Integrating Google Cloud Messaging into Android App - GCM Connection Server

Tags: android, web-services, http

I'm learning android app development, and undertaking a project for educational purposes.

I'm building an app that is like a memory scrapbook - the user can curate scrapbook pages with images imported from their image library, and add written text. There is no server, and the data is stored in XML files.

I've now been tasked with adding a new feature - the ability for users of the app to send each other text based messages to add to a scrapbook page.

I've looked into the Google Cloud Messaging service, and integrating it with my app. I've read that this would involve setting up an application server, to send data via a HTTP or XMPP protocol.

I feel just about proficient enough in java to do the project with the guidance of tutorials, but have no knowledge or experience of servers, or communication protocols.

Can somebody guide me on what is involved in setting up an application server? Or point me in the direction of a tutorial where I can learn more.

Would it involve modifying the way my app currently stores data?

Are there any inherent issues with security that would need to be considered?

And this is highly speculative, but is it feasible for a beginner to undertake in 4 weeks?

Comment: What's wrong with the existing GCM or Firebase messaging tutorials?

Comment: You don't have to configure the HTTP/XMMP connections, all these are done by google payservice on your device . You only have to register for GCM service and handle the messages you receive.
Here is the step by step documentation of GCM from google
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look at the new Firebase service from Google. It is the replacement of the old GCM.

What is firebase:
https://firebase.google.com/features/

Android quickstart guide:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html

Comment: I agree, Firebase provides you with free server plan for up to 100 parallel connections and couple of GBs of bandwidth. Check the pricing here https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ . You'll also be using their proprietary Android APIs which are very easy to learn. You don't have to write even a single line of code for the back-end.